# Running an EXE from azure blob storage with a configuration xml

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

could someone please help me with this? I have issues running an EXE from azure blob storage combined with a configuration file. The exe is called from the blob and then needs an argument that calls an xml configuration file in the same blob directory as the exe file. The exe is called fine but the config file is not. Any ideas?

If i run the c:\temp\setup.exe /configure configuration.xml it runs fine so i'm really not sure?

```
$Path = $env:TEMP
$Installer = "setup.exe"
$OfficeConfig = "configuration.xml"
Invoke-WebRequest "https://********.blob.core.windows.net/office1/setup.exe?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-16T16:00:03Z&st=2019-07-16T08:00:03Z&spr=https&sig=7sO7m3PJMne8hFYAwHY6YFZZG6AfUuhC8x%2BoR7QkWuY%3D" -OutFile $Path\$Installer
Invoke-WebRequest "https://********.blob.core.windows.net/office1/Configuration.xml?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-16T16:00:03Z&st=2019-07-16T08:00:03Z&spr=https&sig=7sO7m3PJMne8hFYAwHY6YFZZG6AfUuhC8x%2BoR7QkWuY%3D" -OutFile $Path\$OfficeConfig
Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Argumentlist'/configure $Path\$OfficeConfig' -Verb RunAs -Wait
Remove-Item $Path\$Installer
```

Comment: Just a guess, shouldn't you be specifying `$Path` for config file as well?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the latest code you’re using.

Comment: Done :) How does that look?

Comment: I’m also not good at PowerShell :) but I noticed there was no space after ‘ArgumentList’. Not sure if that’s causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry I just typed it in above, my actual script does have the space when running in ISE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `single quote` to `double quote` for the `-Argumentlist parameter` in the `Start-Process` cmdlet, like below:

change `-Argumentlist '/configure $Path\$OfficeConfig'` to `-Argumentlist "/configure $Path\$OfficeConfig"`

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe that's all it was, working great now thanks again!